# How to access the current element's attribute in a jQuery expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to call a function on each selected element:

```
$('any valid selector').existingFunction({ p1:<myAttributeValueForTheCurrentElement> });
```

I've tried:

```
$('any valid selector').existingFunction({ p1: this.attr('myAttributeValueForTheCurrentElement') });
```

but apparently this refers to HTMLDocument because I got the error message:
'Object # has no method 'attr''

Comment: show us your original html & jquery, reproducible jsfiddle would help more.

Comment: `this` here refers to window object which as all DOM object doesn't has an attr method, not as jq object got

Comment: What interest do you got in passing to `existingFunction` function a parameter containing an information about the current element ? You can always get it in the function body with `$(this).attr('myAttributeValueForTheCurrentElement')`

Comment: The way I see it you have two options either enhance the `existingFunction` plugin to accept function as the property value...or use a `each` loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is bound to the outer scope.

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
var obj = { p1: this.attr('myAttributeValueForTheCurrentElement') };

$('any valid selector').existingFunction(obj);
```

You are going to need to iterate over the elements in the collection.

```
$('selector').each(function(){

   var options = { p1: $(this).attr('myAttributeValueForTheCurrentElement') };

   $(this).existingFunction(options);

});
```

Comment: Someone want to explain the -1. For what exactly do you find wrong with the above code?

Comment: @MelanciaUK ***What***? Downvoters are a healthy and vital part of this site. They're the reason Stack Overflow is as successful as it is.

Comment: @meagar - Sure, but downvoting without explanation is pretty lame.

Comment: @Josh Again, this is *fundamentally* important to the site. Downvoting is anonymous by design. The ability to downvote bad content without fear of reprisal is another *key* component in Stack Overflow's success. Downvotes are and will always be an important part of the site. The problem is when people take them personally, not that they exist in the first place.

Comment: @meagar - I get it. It's just frustrating when you answer something correctly, or at least functionally correct, and are downvoted either maliciously, or ignorantly. In the end the voting usually wins out, and good answers rise to the top. It's a minor nit, and one I can live with. Doesn't make it any less crappy when it happens :)